# Unable to save data to mongo(skin) sent via $.ajax PUT

Tags: javascript, jquery, mongodb, express, mongoskin

I have used $.ajax to send a PUT request through to my Express server. I can retrieve the information just fine but am having difficulties saving the new changes to my mongo (via mongoskin) database.

From the top, here is my click event on an edit button:

```
$('#userList table tbody').on('click', 'td a.linkedituser', editUser);
```

And here the function it calls:

```
function editUser(event) {
  event.preventDefault();

  var thisUserID = $(this).attr('rel');
  var arrayPosition = userListData.map(function(arrayItem) { return arrayItem._id; }).indexOf(thisUserID);
  var thisUserObject = userListData[arrayPosition];

  $('#editUserName').val(thisUserObject.email);
  $('#editUserEmail').val(thisUserObject.email);
  $('#editUserFullname').val(thisUserObject.fullname);
  $('#editUserAge').val(thisUserObject.age);
  $('#editUserLocation').val(thisUserObject.location);
  $('#editUserGender').val(thisUserObject.gender);

  $('#btnEditUser').on('click', function() {
    $.ajax({
      type: 'PUT',
      url: '/users/edituser',
      data: {
        'id' : thisUserID,
        'username' : $('#editUserName').val(),
        'email' : $('#editUserEmail').val(),
        'fullname' : $('#editUserFullname').val(),
        'age' : $('#editUserAge').val(),
        'location' : $('#editUserLocation').val(),
        'gender' : $('#editUserGender').val()
      },
      dataType: 'json',
      success: function(msg) {},
      error: function(err) {}
    }).done(function(response) {
      if (response.msg === '') {
      }
      else {
      }
      populateTable();
    });
  });
};
```

And finally the router file routes/users.js

```
router.put('/edituser', function(req, res) {
  var db = req.db;
  db.collection('userlist').findById(req.body.id, function(err, result) {
    result.username = req.body.username;
    result.email = req.body.email;
    result.fullname = req.body.fullname;
    result.age = req.body.age;
    result.location = req.body.location;
    result.gender = req.body.gender;

    console.log(result);

    res.send((result === 1) ? { msg: '' } : { msg: 'error: ' + err + "!!!!" });
  });
});
```

[Everything is on git](https://github.com/WayneHaworth/nodetest2.git) should I have missed anything.

It seems like everything should be fine but the results are not saving. When I refresh the page or click the edit button the old values return. I tried 'results.save()' but I get an error that the function does not exist.

Should I not be using findById?

Thanks.

Comment: I'm not familiar with mongoskin but I think you want to use `updateById` not `findById`

Comment: This works a treat, thanks :) Go create an answer so I can tick it.